# Hover on a table-cell css displayed on all row

Tags: css, hover, tablecell

I'm struggling to understand why my container (table-cell) don't behave how I wish I want :)

Situation : I created a div container (bouton) with 2 div inside (image and text).
What I want : hover anywhere on the container will apply a background-color.
Problem : I added a background-color hover to the div container (bouton) but instead of just applying it to all the div "bouton" it applies it to the all row.

Here is the Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/gicspy/qotv4yz0/3/

HTML :

```
<div id="bouton">
  <a href="/test/" title="test">
    <div class="bouton-image">
      <img class="clear-btn-devis" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x120" width="100" height="120">
    </div>
    <div class="bouton-texte">
      THIS IS CONTENT FOR THE BUTTON
      <br /><span style="font-size:90% !important;"><p style="line-height: 1 !important;">(with more information even)</p></span>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#bouton div {
  display: table-cell;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #1ac658;
  color: #ffffff !important;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.bouton-image {
  display: table;
  border-radius: 3px 0px 0px 3px;
  min-width: 70px !important;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bouton-texte {
  border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 0px;
  font-size: 130%;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#bouton:hover,
#bouton:active {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  background-color: #f6416c !important;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 13px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 4px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

I've been looking but I'm missing something on how the table-cell behaves.

Any one can help ?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: text-align, inline-block and vertical-aline go along fine : https://jsfiddle.net/qotv4yz0/4/ ;)  pointer-events and display for <a> for hover effects https://jsfiddle.net/qotv4yz0/5/

Answer (score 0):

You applied the background and shadow to `#bouton`. You need to apply it to the `div`s inside it:

```
#bouton div:hover,
#bouton div:active
```

This will give you what you want, but you have several other issues:

- You cannot place `div` inside `a`.
- You're trying to display table inside cell, which doesn't make sense.
- You don't even need these display types. The `div` is capable of doing what you want without changing its display type.

Here is some code that gets you close to what you want. You can tweak it to your liking, but it will get you started:

```css
#bouton a {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #1ac658;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 400px;
}

.bouton-image {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}

.bouton-texte {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 130%;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 300px;
}

#bouton a:hover,
#bouton a:active {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  background-color: #f6416c !important;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 13px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 4px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

```html
<div id="bouton">
  <a href="/test/" title="test">
    <span class="bouton-image">
      <img class="clear-btn-devis" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x120" width="100" height="120">
    </span>
    <span class="bouton-texte">
      THIS IS CONTENT FOR THE BUTTON
      <br /><span style="font-size:90% !important;"><p style="line-height: 1 !important;">(with more information even)</p></span>
    </span>
    <br style="clear: both;" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and help.

My goal is to have a button with 1 image and some text next to it. I want everything to be center vertically and horizontally that's why I tried with the way of table cell... maybe it doesnt make any sense and there is an easier way to reach this : stackoverflow.com/questions/13983522/… .The problem is that this solution, is that the text when on multiple raws will go under the image and I want it to stay on the right... sorry for this mess but thx for your help!

Comment: I also tried to apply the background on both divs (text and image) but the problem is that I want both divs to have the hover, in the same time. Not only one or the other..

Comment: They currently have green background, so anything behind them will not be visible. You'll have to merge them in one `div`.